# update table when row value is not equal to specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a object like this

```
{ emId: '1', emEmail: 'sreepurna@xxx.com' }
```

I am using nodejs at backend and mysql for database. I want to update table only when my value is not equal to specific value. Is there any possibility to write this within a query.

I tried the few sql statements but it doesnt work:

```
let sql = `UPDATE details SET name = CASE WHEN '${req.body.emName}' != 'hi' THEN ${req.body.emName} END where id=${req.body.emId}`;
```

Comment: Undefined is special to JS. These type checkings should be done outside of the query.

Comment: @revo thanks for the info. But I still remain with a question. What if i dont what to update the cell value with specific value? For this also do we need to do a manual check? or is there any other way?

Comment: Then your query could be like this `UPDATE details SET name = '${req.body.emName}' WHERE id = ${req.body.emId} AND '${req.body.emName}' <> 'hi'`

Comment: @revo Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a thing called `undefined` inside the SQL language, you have to validate your values via JavaScript

```js
if(req.body.emName){
  // This code block will run when req.body.emName contains value and is not undefined or null
  let sql = `UPDATE details SET name = CASE WHEN '${req.body.emName}' THEN ${req.body.emName} END where id=${req.body.emId}`;
}else{
  // req.body.emName is either empty/undefined or null
  // ...
}
```